# In Subversion, how do I verify that everything was successfully loaded into the repository?

Tags: svn, validation, repository, verification

I have got a Subversion repository, but how can I tell if it really has everything it's supposed to?

The file and folder counts are widely different between the Working Folder and the original folder I used to create the repository, even accounting for the contents of the .svn folder in each repository folder. (assuming they all are the same, which may not be valid.)  It doesn't match the sandbox 'practice' repository I created on a different server, either.

I'm so new to Subversion that I still have those protective plastic tabs on my displays, so if I'm asking a silly question, please be understanding. I couldn't find anything for this in the manual or on this site.

The import and commits all say 'complete' and such, with no errors (at this point) but I'd like to find a way to be absolutely sure everything is in there. There's over 1.6 gigs of data in 30,000+ files, so I don't really want to compare two lists or eyeball it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svn status` in the top level of the working directory will show you all files that aren't committed. As for `svn import`, it will normally output the list of file it imports when you run it, which should give you a good idea on whether it worked.

I'd say "trust your tools to do what they say they do" (i.e. `svn import` will have imported all those files, trust me), but if you want to be really really sure you can export from your working copy or the repository to elsewhere, i.e. from the working copy directory:

```
svn export . ../test
```

And then run a diff utility on this directory and your original directory. They should be carbon copies if you haven't committed any changes yet.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [svn status](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re26.html) command you can list the files that are not under version control.

```
svn status | grep -e ^?
```